# classic asp and soap response - how to handle changing prefixes in namespace?

Tags: soap, asp-classic, wsdl

I have inherited a classic asp page that uses webservices, which is something I'm relatively new to. The requests and responses work fine, but I have noticed that a prefix gets added to the namespace somewhere between the wsdl and me reading it. So a namespace `<FirstName>` will turn out `<ns2:FirstName>` or sometimes `<ns3:FirstName>` or sometimes just `<FirstName>`. It's the exact same element, but the prefix changes every so often. 
I've been told that I'm reading the response "raw", and I need to filter out these extra-generated-prefixes, but I don't know how.
Here is a code snippet of how I use the webservice (some stuff has been modified to keep this simple) :

```
Dim oXmlHTTP, objxml, SOAPRequest, SOAPResponse

    Set oXmlHTTP = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.3.0")
    oXmlHTTP.open "POST", "http://something.com/something/services/something?wsdl", False 
    oXmlHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=UTF-8" 

    SOAPRequest = _
    "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' xmlns:head='http://header.something.com" xmlns:ser='http://service.something.com' xmlns:add='http://service.something.com/domain/address'>" &_
       "<soapenv:Body>" &_
          "<ser:getInfo>" &_
             "<add:ID>123</add:ID>" &_
          "</ser:getInfo>" &_
       "</soapenv:Body>" &_
    "</soapenv:Envelope>"

    On Error Resume Next
    oXmlHTTP.send SOAPRequest   

    If Err.Number Then 
        Response.Write("Error: " & Err.Description)
        Err.Clear 
    Else 
        SOAPResponse = oXmlHTTP.responseText

    End If 
    On Error Goto 0 

    If LEN(SOAPResponse) > 0 then
        Set objxml = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.3.0")
        objxml.async = False
        objxml.load (oXmlHTTP.responseXML)      

        If objxml.parseError.errorCode <> 0 Then
             Response.Write("XML error")
        End If

        'This is where the "error" will occur, as the <Firstname> sometimes isn't recognized, and I must search for e.g. <ns2:Firstname> instead
        Set nodeList = objxml.getElementsByTagName("FirstName")
        SizeofObject = nodeList.length-1

        For i = 0 To (SizeofObject)  
            Response.Write ("Name: " & objxml.getElementsByTagName("FirstName").item(i).Text)
        Next    


    End If
        Set oXmlHTTP = Nothing 
        SOAPRequest = ""
        SOAPResponse = ""
```

How can I ignore these "random" prefixes that might occur? Is there a better practice to use a webservice calls in classic asp? (changing to .NET is not an option right now). Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use VBScript's Replace function to to change the Firstname tags to just `<Firstname>`?

eg

```
Set objxml = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")
objxml.async = False
Dim MyResponse
MyResponse = oXmlHTTP.responseXML
MyResponse = Replace(MyResponse,"<ns2:FirstName>","<FirstName>")
MyResponse = Replace(MyResponse,"<ns3:FirstName>","<FirstName>")
objxml.load (MyResponse)
```

NB I generally recommend calling version 6 rather than version 3 of MSXML - it's the most recent version

Comment: That could work, but I was more interested if there was a "proper" way of handling this, where I avoid these generated prefixes altogether.